# Using An Embeded Google Map On A Website?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to use an emebeded Google Map on my website with pure CSS?

```
<div class="map"></div>
```

```
.map{
  background: url("https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d4450.37576469368!2d47.31305345548099!3d56.101968401211494!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x39a74418f9829faa!2z0J_QtdGA0LXQutGA0LXRgdGC0L7Qug!5e0!3m2!1sru!2sru!4v1600523332413!5m2!1sru!2sru");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u36yxkde/

If possible, what parameters should I set in CSS to see the map?

Comment: want to achieve it using CSS background

Comment: Use the URL in your browser and see that there is no picture for this URL. You can set an image, not include a whole google map. What you could eventually do is include a google map in your webpage, then add an overlay with whatever you want above it, but that's not really what you've asked.

Comment: Can you elaborate the "want to achieve it using CSS background" ?

Comment: The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe. Probably not.

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

Comment: what's the final purpose ? , an absolute iframe could fake it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe.

Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but it is likely the user will not be able to interact with it. Maps are also heavy assets to load in the browser so consider that when building your page.

My suggestion would to be adding the map to an object and placing that at full width/height in the background (ex: `z-index: -1`)

Here is an example

https://jsfiddle.net/qe6wm3fd/2/